# Is there a way to update set of rows in Postgres against a UUID array?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am having a problem in sending my array of UUID in an update Query.

My UUID array looks like this:

```
[
    "c5cahude-8245-49ed-b2d2-niufu",
    "b272jiopeb-486c-495f-91a4-zokxp",
    "kodeidji-1487-4d02-a958-901i9"
]
```

I have tried to use .join() and .toString() but it did not work. My last option was to create something by sending it through a map function. I am not satisfied with this piece of code.

My current code looks something like this right now.

```
const params: string = _.map(ids, (s, i) => `$${i + offset}`).join(',');
const query = `update some_table set deleted = NOW(), fk_updated_by = $${ids.length + 1} where id IN(${params})`;
```

The output is correct but i want to implement something much more simpler.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Prepared statements work with arrays, so I'm assuming they will work with array of UUID just fine.

> node-postgres supports mapping simple JavaScript arrays to PostgreSQL
>   arrays, so in most cases you can just pass it like any other
>   parameter.

```
client.query("SELECT * FROM stooges WHERE name = ANY ($1)", [ ['larry', 'curly', 'moe'] ], ...);
```

https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/FAQ#11-how-do-i-build-a-where-foo-in--query-to-find-rows-matching-an-array-of-values

https://node-postgres.com/features/queries#prepared-statements